# How to fatch Google Analytics raw data for my custom report?

Tags: android, mysql, google-analytics

I have created mobile app in android with google Analytics api. and watching all the reports on google portal. Now I want that all data to create custom report match with another data stored in my database (e.g.mysql). So I have to download that data and import in to my database. Does google provide that data?

Comment: Google Analytics won't provide raw data.

Comment: the Google analytics api allows you to download the data.   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/  You might want to start with the documentation.

Comment: @DaImTo, Thanks for reply. I have seen that document. but I think, It provide only aggregate data with metrics. (correct me, If I am wrong). As I mention in Question, I need raw data, to compare and analyse with another data stored in my database.

Comment: As @Raptor said there is no way to get Raw data from Google Analytics.  The only way to Extract data from Google analytics is though the Google Analytics API.   The only other option would be if you had a premium google analytics account there are a few extra features with that big query is one.  If you are a premium Google Analytics customer you can contact your account manager for help.

Comment: Another way might be to use a proxy service like Segment (https://segment.com/ - have not used them, just the first I found) that allows you to send the same data to multiple services. Of course that would require a new version of your app with the segment sdk integrated.